# Gensim train word2vec and Fasttext

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim

I need to train my own model with word2vec and fasttext. By readind different sourcs I found different information. 
So I did the model and trained it like this:

```
model = FastText(all_words, size=300, min_count= 3,sg=1)
model = Word2Vec(all_words, min_count=3, sg = 1, size = 300 )
```

So I read that that should be enough to creat and train the model. But then I saw, that some people do it seperatly:

```
model = FastText(size=4, window=3, min_count=1)  # instantiate
model.train(sentences=common_texts, total_examples=len(common_texts), epochs=10)  # train
```

Now I am confused and dont know if what I did is correct. Can sombody help me to make it clear? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly acceptable to supply your training corpus – `all_words` – when you instantiate the model object. In that case, the model will automatically perform all steps needed to train the model, using that data. So you can do this:

```py
model = Word2Vec(all_words, ...)  # where '...' is your non-default params
```

It's also acceptable to not provide the corpus when instantiating the model - but then the model is extremely minimal, with just your initial parameters. It still needs to discover the relevant vocabulary (which requires a single pass over the training data), then allocate some vary-large internal structures to accommodate those words, then do the actual training (which requires multiple additional passes over the training data).

So if you don't provide the corpus when the model is instantiated, you should do *two* extra method calls:

```py
model = Word2Vec(...)  # where '...' is your non-default params
model.build_vocab(all_words)  # discover vocabulary & allocate model
# now train, with #-of-passes & #-of-texts set by earlier steps
model.train(all_words, epochs=model.iter, total_examples=model.corpus_count)
```

These two code blocks I've shown are equivalent. The top does the usual steps for you; the bottom breaks the steps out into your explicit control.

(The code you'd excerpted in your question, showing **only** a `.train()` call, would error for a number of reasons. The `.build_vocab()` is a necessary step to have a fully-allocated model, and the call to `.train()` must explicitly state the desired `epochs` and an accurate count `total_examples` of the number-of-items in the corpus. But, you can and typically should re-use values that were already cached into the `model` by the two previous steps.)

It's your choice which approach to use. Generally people only use the 3-separate-steps process if they want to do other output/logging between the steps, or something advanced between the steps that might tamper with the model state.